# Read ElasticSearch Index from Java

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to read an **ElasticSearch** (1.4) index from a Java program, but I don't really have an idea where to start.

I don't have a running ES instance so I cannot use the "normal" API.

What I understand is the acual index files are **Lucene** so there must be a way to read them. Performance is not an issue, so I don't mind if the program runs a little longer (or even all night).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right **Elasticsearch** index (on one shard) just a normal *Lucene* index, so it's really easy to open it in Java program using *Lucene*.

Most simple way to do that is below:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_PATH)));
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
```

It's **Lucene 5.0**, but **Lucene 4.xx** will be similar to this:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(INDEX_PATH)), true);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
```