# Elasticsearch Java API - how do I delete document based on field?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I would like to delete a document based on a specific field that is not the `_id` field, which is required in the following:

```
DeleteResponse response = NodeClient()
    .prepareDelete("user_name", "user_type", field_var)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

I tried something similar to the following:

```
DeleteByQueryResponse response = client.prepareDeleteByQuery(“test”)
    .setQuery(termQuery(”_type”, “type1”))
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

But it appears to be deprecated in ES 2.1.

Comment: Maybe this help you [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33855324/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33855324/3710490)

Comment: @Valijon damn that sucks.. thanks anyways. :)

Comment: What about to read Elasticsearch index via Lucene and delete rows by query? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916112/read-elasticsearch-index-from-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916112/read-elasticsearch-index-from-java)